# PHP - Display the current date in words?

Tags: php

Is there a way to use getdate (or similar) to output the current day in a format like this

```
twenty october twenty ten
```

I can't have the year as 'two thousand ten' due to space restrictions so it just needs to be 'twenty eleven' 'twenty twelve' etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Follow [this tutorial](http://www.phpro.org/examples/Convert-Numbers-to-Words.html) then apply results to your date.

<sub>Note: you need to split year to two parts: 2010 = 20, 10</sub>

Comment: A lot of that is superfluous for this, since nothing above 99 would be needed. In fact, assuming a 32-bit time field, nothing above 38 would be needed, either. Of course, it's good to have the future in mind, as well as re-use in case you need to format other, larger numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with PHP's `date` function. You can only output the month as string. To do what you asked for you need to get a number to word function (plenty are available out there) and apply it on your day - `numberToWord( date('j') )`, first part of the year - `numberToWord( substr(date('Y'), 0, 2) )` and second part of the year - `numberToWord( substr(date('Y'), 2, 2) )`. The month is `date('F')`.